# What's a better way to compare two object booleans in this scenario?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

What’s a better way of writing this statement? While this works. I feel there's a much more succinct way of doing this. Preferably an ES6 method.

```
var show = [
    {
        name: 'Active',
        slug: 'active',
        enabled: true
    },
    {
        name: 'Inactive',
        slug: 'inactive',
        enabled: true
    }
]

var isActive = null;

if (show[0].enabled && show[1].enabled) {
    isActive = null; // if both true
} else if (show[0].enabled) {
    isActive = true; // if only active is true
} else if (show[1].enabled) {
    isActive = false; // if only inactive is true
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/udL7ob72/1/

Comment: So if neither is enabled you want to stick with the default of `null`?

Comment: Ternary logic is weird. Do you really need to use `null` and `true` and `false`?

Comment: You might want to look into _boolean blindness_ and _primitive obsession_

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @ftor I'll have a read. Care to expand? The reason this is not as simple as it could be is because the api I'm working with has a flag for `is_active`. If true, it returns all active items. If false it returns all inactive items. If null (or not included in the request params) it returns both active and inactive. The UI has 2 checkboxes "Show active" and "Show Inactive". This is how I've come to the current solution, however I'm not exactly thrilled by it.

Comment: Often it is more convenient to have radio buttons, which always describe both cases, whereas check boxes always hide one. I am far from being a front end expert, though. Here is a video that you might like: [Solving the boolean identity crises](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TDKHGtAxeg&feature=youtu.be).

Comment: Thanks ftor. I agree, radio buttons are a much better solution for this :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
var isActive = show[0].enabled != show[1].enabled // if exactly one is true
                 ? show[0].enabled // same as !show[1].enabled
                 : null;
```

however I would recommend not to use a nullable boolean variable.

```js
function getActive(show) {
  var isActive = show[0].enabled != show[1].enabled // if exactly one is true
               ? show[0].enabled // same as !show[1].enabled
               : null;
  console.log(show[0].enabled, show[1].enabled, isActive)
  return isActive;
}
getActive([{enabled: true},{enabled: true}]);
getActive([{enabled: false},{enabled: true}]);
getActive([{enabled: true},{enabled: false}]);
getActive([{enabled: false},{enabled: false}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a ternary and check if the value is equal, the return `null`, otherwise just the value of `show[0].enabled`.

> Table of Truth
>
> ```
>   [0]      [1]     result
> -------  -------  --------
>  false    false     null
>  false    true      false
>  true     false     true
>  true     true      null
> ```

```
var isActive = show[0].enabled === show[1].enabled
        ? null
        : show[0].enabled;
```

Comment: it return null, as desired.

Comment: There's a duplicated `isActive =` left in here

Comment: I really don't understand how this answer had 5 votes less than mine, while it's doing essentially the same just with the inverse condition

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
(show[0].enabled && !show[1].enabled) || (!show[0].enabled && show[1].enabled ? false : null );
```

**Demo**

```js
console.log( "true false -> ",  getIsActive( [{"enabled":true},{"enabled":false}] ) );
console.log( "false false -> ", getIsActive( [{"enabled":false},{"enabled":false}] ) );
console.log( "true true -> ", getIsActive( [{"enabled":true},{"enabled":true}] ) );
console.log( "false true -> ", getIsActive( [{"enabled":false},{"enabled":true}] ) );

function getIsActive( show )
{
  return (show[0].enabled && !show[1].enabled) || (!show[0].enabled && show[1].enabled ? false : null );
}
```